# gnuplot multiplot layout not being overridden by set origin, ways to position subplots

Tags: gnuplot

This question is to some part identical to what has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54157057/overriding-gnuplot-multiplot-layout). But the referenced question never received the answer to the point whether the issue presented here is a bug or documentation confusion.

Documentation states with respect to the `layout` option of `multiplot`:

> With the layout option you can generate simple multiplots without
> having to give the set size and set origin commands before each plot:
> Those are generated automatically, but can be overridden at any time.

My understanding of that text is that layout sets origin and size and at any time, i can change those specifications. Then this should work:

```
set xrange [0:10]
set multiplot layout 3,1 margins 0.1,0.95,0.12,0.95 spacing 0,0
unset key
plot cos(x) axes x1y1 w l ls 3 notitle
plot sin(x) axes x1y1 w l ls 3 notitle
set key bottom center out horizontal
plot sin(x) axes x1y1 w l ls 3 notitle
set origin 0.3,0.5
set size 0.2,0.1
set xrange [1:2]
plot cos(x) axes x1y1 w l ls 3 notitle
unset multiplot
```

But it does not. `gnuplot` completely ignores `set size` and `set origin` commands. What it should do is to plot 3 plots under each other and then create an inset at screen position `(0.3,0.5)` of size relative to canvas `(0.2,0.1)`.

My questions are:

1. Is this a bug that should be reported or is this poorly formulated documentation issue (that layout can be overridden by `set position` and `set size`)?
2. `multiplot` offers two ways to position the sub-plots, `set origin` + `set size` and `set *margin` where `*` stands for one of `b,t,l,r`. Can someone provide a deeper explanation when one should use which? (For me it feels the proper way that was meant to do it is `set origin` and  margins just became a dirty trick that works but was not meant for that)
3. What would be the cleanest way to produce the plot that I am looking for that would be easily reproducible (for any other problem, not just 3 plots but any plots and without some tedious calculations of positions)?
4. Is there a way to print the settings of `origin`, `size`, margins and any other relevant settings that are automatically calculated (and used) when the `layout` option is specified?

Comment: maybe this also might be helpful... https://stackoverflow.com/q/65640035/7295599

Comment: @theozh thanks for the link, it will surely come helpful!

Comment: another post about "automatic" multiplot layout... although not for insets. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56478134/7295599

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. My guess would be that it is a bit unclear documentation.
2. It's a matter of taste and convenience and depends on your situation. Setting origin and size is setting the place for the (sub-)"canvas". This (sub-)"canvas" still can have some individual b,t,l,r margins. Note, margins are the space between graph border and canvas-border.
3. Apparently, the margins which you are setting in the multiplot layout are kept for your extra plot.
   So, apparently you have to reset them, e.g. `set margins 0,0,0,0`. And then you are probably getting your intended plot.
4. I am not aware that you can extract the automatically calculated values for margins. There are no such values
   listed in `show var GPVAL`.

**Code:**

```
### multiplot layout with manual origin and size
reset session

set xrange [0:10]
unset key
set ytics 0.5

set multiplot layout 3,1 margins 0.1,0.95,0.12,0.95 spacing 0,0

    plot cos(x) axes x1y1 w l ls 3 notitle
    
    plot sin(x) axes x1y1 w l ls 3 notitle

    set key bottom center out horizontal
    plot sin(x) axes x1y1 w l ls 3 notitle

    set margins 0,0,0,0
    set origin 0.3,0.5
    set size 0.2,0.1
    set xrange [1:2]
    plot cos(x) axes x1y1 w l ls 3 notitle
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Good catch with the margins. I implemented this feature many years ago, but didn't remember the details. Generally one can use either `set origin` and `set size`,  or `set margins`. If both are used,  the margins win. Maybe I can find a clearer formulation for the docs.